# P value is not significant, but most rates in treatment group are systematic higher than that in control group

Tags: p-value, sample-size

I am analyzing adverse events rate in two groups, treatment and control group. There are about 10 different adverse events. Most of the rates are not significantly different between these two groups, however, the rates are systematically higher in the treatment group. What does that mean? Is it related to sample size?
[image]

Comment: It might be meaningless.  The key is to assess the degree to which these ten events might be correlated.  If you can argue they are independent, then you can "chunk" them and perform an "omnibus" test using an F-ratio statistic and almost surely it would have a very tiny p-value, reflecting the consistency of ten independent events.  It would help to know (much) more about what an "adverse event" means and how they were measured or observed.  What is the experimental design?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The power of the test is based on sample size yes, but more importantly on the amount of events. All proportions of events are very low, (e.g., 0.35% of 4000 = 0.0035 * 4000 = 14 events. This considerably limits the power of your statistical test. Therefore, there is much uncertainty whether these differences are truly systematic.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input. Then is there any better way to do the test?

Comment: Not really, it seems as though this analysis is just underpowered. You could look at the total count of adverse events by adding all of them up, just to see if the total amount of adverse events (regardless of type) differs between groups (at which point you have more events to power a test), but this might not be your research question.

Comment: You are right, the sum of adverse events is not really what I am interested in. Thank you.

Comment: If you feel like your question is sufficiently answered, you can [accept](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) the answer, showing other users that your question was resolved (however, don't feel forced to).

Comment: I think much more information about the question needs to be disclosed before this or any answer is accepted.

Comment: I am reluctant to release more information, since this is a trial. And I did modified some of the data, But it does reflect the original data information. Those adverse events, some are independent, some are not.

Comment: Nobody is asking for privileged information, genomy, but some account of what kind of data you are dealing with and how you collected it is essential.  In most of the ways I can find to interpret your question, this answer is either misleading or wrong, which is why I am concerned.